# AND gate IC with internal pullup

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I'm currently using a dual-input AND gate similar to the [Texas Instruments SN74LVC2G08](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc2g08.pdf).

I'm wondering if any manufacturers make an AND gate with internal pull-ups so the inputs would default to TRUE when the device driving them tri-states. If so, can anyone point me to an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should both inputs default to high? Why not make a separate model for every combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs of bipolar TTL logic (74xx, 74LSxx) normallly appear as High when not connected - but even with them, it is advised to provide a pull-up resistor to ensure that unconnected inputs will really be taken as High.

CMOS parts (74HCxx, 74ACxx, etc.) have very high input impedances, and MUST have a pull-up or pull-down resistor to be reliably detected as High or Low, respectively.

Added, following a "not an answer" comment:

I'm not aware of any common logic parts (gates, flipflops, counters...) that have built-in pull-up resistors on their inputs, but many microcontrollers do have pull-up resistors that can be enabled or disabled by software on their I/O pins.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I also heard back from a Texas Instruments FAE that they do not have a version in IPUs.